# VBA/Excel, Why IF condition has no effect with Row Height in this code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code to set `Row Height of Range` to not less than 45.
This line of code works  `Rng.EntireRow.RowHeight = 45`
But If I used it with IF condition , It has no effect at all.
I tried to replace  EntireRow with ROWS , but also no effect.

```
Sub Row_Height()

    Dim Rng As Range
    
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A3", Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    If Rng.EntireRow.RowHeight < 45 Then
       Rng.EntireRow.RowHeight = 45
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rng` is not a single cell, so the rows in it could all have different heights.

Loop thru the rows in it instead so you can check the height one by one.

```
Sub Row_Height()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A3", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    For Each r In Rng.Rows
        If r.RowHeight < 45 Then r.RowHeight = 45
    Next
End Sub
```